# opera browser not loading the page using selenium Rc(Java)

Tags: selenium-rc

I have a suite of Selenium tests (created using Java  in Selenium RC 1.0.3) that work perfectly with IE, Firefox and Google 
Chrome. But when I try to use Opera (I tried both versions 9 and 10) 
the first "open" command times out (both windows open but the target 
page is never loaded).

Has anybody made Opera work with Selenium RC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a "true" argument to each open() (or, using the perl driver, open_ok())  function call .Then it works with opera 10. Not tested with Opera 11 (just released in 2011).

Example.

```
$sel->open_ok("/page.php?id=3027"); #WRONG

$sel->open_ok("/page.php?id=3027", "true"); #RIGHT
```